# How to set up a bind9 DNS server to forward DNS requests to iodine?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I'm trying to demo iodine in my LAN. I have an iodine client machine, an iodine server machine with the hostname `t1.haxor.com` and a locally running DNS server.

I want to imitate an enterprise environment where only DNS requests to the enterprise DNS server are allowed. Therefore, the client machine is only allowed to send packets over port 53 to the local DNS server. I don't want to pay for a public domain, so I want to setup the local DNS server to forward DNS request querying `*.haxor.com` to the iodine server.

Simply put, I want the iodine server to be the nameserver for `*.haxor.com` in my LAN.

I attempted to create a zone for `haxor.com`, according to the [iodine github readme](https://github.com/yarrick/iodine#server-side). However, I failed.

```
$TTL 10
@       IN      SOA     ns.haxor.com. admin.haxor.com. (
        1       ;serial number
        10      ;time to refresh
        10      ;time to retry
        604800  ;time to expire
        10 )    ;minimum TTL

        IN      NS      ns.haxor.com.

;address to name mapping
t1.haxor.com.   IN      NS      ns.haxor.com.
ns.haxor.com.   IN      A       IP-ADDRESS-OF-IODINE-SERVER
```

The `named.conf.local` configuration:

```
zone "haxor.com" {
   type master;
   file "/etc/bind/zones/db.haxor.com";
};
```

How can I configure bind9 to send DNS requests for `*.haxor.com` to the iodine server?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**The problem**

I'm pretty sure the problem is that in `named.conf.local`, I set up the type of the `haxor.com` zone to be `master`. I assume master is supposed to be the definitive authority on the zone, and that's why it didn't forward the requests. Please correct me if I am wrong.

**My solution:**

I installed bind9 on the DNS server:

`apt install bind9`

I also setup logging and forwarding according to [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SATEOZwjw4U). However, I think this step is unnecessary.

Then, I went to `/etc/bind/named.conf.local` and added the following:

```
zone "haxor.com." {
        type forward;
        forward only;
        forwarders { YOUR-IODINE-SERVER-IP-ADDRESS-HERE port 53; };
};
```

Make sure to change `YOUR-IODINE-SERVER-IP-ADDRESS-HERE` to the correct IP address. This configuration will forward all DNS requests for the zone `haxor.com` to your iodine server.

Then, on the server, start iodine:

`iodined -f 10.0.0.1 t1.haxor.com -P password`

This command assumes your machines are not in a 10.0.0.0 network. If it is, you will have to specify an IP address from some other IP range. Note that `10.0.0.1` is not the iodine server's current IP address, instead it is an arbitrary desired IP address for the DNS tunnel.

And on the client, start iodine:

`iodine -f -r IP-ADDRESS-OF-YOUR-LOCAL-DNS-SERVER t1.haxor.com -P password`

Make sure to change `IP-ADDRESS-OF-YOUR-LOCAL-DNS-SERVER` to the IP address of the DNS server you configured the forwarding on.

And that's it! You should then have a working DNS tunnel. You can verify it by running the following command on the client machine:

`ping 10.0.0.1`

The ping should be successful.

Comment: I don't think this will work in a real-world scenario where the DNS queries are forced to go through a separate recursive DNS resolver (e.g. "enterprise" DNS server) that is not under your control. The separate resolver will send queries to your bind9 server with the "Recursion desired" flag set to "no", which means forwarding options will not apply.

Comment: Instead, you want to use delegation, i.e. add a NS record for a subdomain that points to the IP that iodine is listening on. Note, however, that this requires separate IP addresses for the parent domain and the subdomain, or the use of clever tricks like some kind of DNS reverse proxy that knows how to route incoming requests to a single IP between bind and iodine. (iodine's -b option is an example of this, but it does come with caveats.)